# JPA Specification subquery for List

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have a entity called ApplicationDocumentLink define like this:

```
public class ApplicationDocumentLink{
//id and some other fields
private List<Long> expertIds
private Long appId;
```

And I have a builder method:

```
    public MyBuilder expert(final Long expert){
        if(Objects.nonNull(expert)){
            Subquery<List> applicationDocumentLinkSubQuery = query.subquery(List.class);
            Root<ApplicationDocumentLink> applicationDocumentLinkSubRoot = applicationDocumentLinkSubQuery.from(ApplicationDocumentLink.class);
            applicationDocumentLinkSubQuery.select(applicationDocumentLinkSubRoot.get("expertIds")).distinct(true).where(
                    criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("id"),(applicationDocumentLinkSubRoot.get("appId"))
            ));
            predicates.add(
                    criteriaBuilder.in(criteriaBuilder.literal(expert)).value(applicationDocumentLinkSubQuery)
            );

        }
        return this;
    }
```

Is there anything wrong on doing query.subquery(List.class)?
Because Im receiving the message:
"Cannot resolve method 'value(Subquery);"

How can I approach to fetch the other entity by mi root id which is represented by appId and select the list of expertId?